# Image taking me to a webpage without having a link attached

Tags: html, css

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to remove an unattached link to one of my images. It's acting as a hyperlink to another page without actually having a link attached.

I've made 2 columns and have images on both sides. The left column takes me to one page and the right takes me to another. Except the right takes me to the same webpage as the left column without having that href attached.

Here's the code I have written. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been completely stumped.

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
            <div id="left_col">
                <span><img src="images/puppy.jpg" style="border: 3px solid #fc5c3c" alt="pupper" width="300px" height="200px"></span>
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        <a class="pup" href="corgipuppies.html"><h2>Corgi Puppies</h2><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="images/bone.png" alt="corgibone" width="75" height="75" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="col_right">
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                            <span><img src="images/puppy1.jpg" style="border: 3px solid #fc5c3c" alt="pupper1" width="300px" height="200px"></span>
                        <a class="pup1" href="naturecorgis.html"><h2>Nature Corgis</h2><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="images/bone.png" alt="corgibone" width="75" height="75" />
                    </div>
            </div>
```

I just want to know why there's a link on my second image that's not supposed to be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ain't closed your first `<a>`, before `<h2>Corgi Puppies</h2>`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
<div id="wrap">
        <div id="left_col">
            <span><img src="images/puppy.jpg" style="border: 3px solid #fc5c3c" alt="pupper" width="300px" height="200px"></span>
                <div style="text-align: center">
                <a class="pup" href="corgipuppies.html"><h2>Corgi Puppies</h2><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="images/bone.png" alt="corgibone" width="75" height="75" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="col_right">
                <div style="text-align: center">
                        <span><img src="images/puppy1.jpg" style="border: 3px solid #fc5c3c" alt="pupper1" width="300px" height="200px"></span>
                    <a class="pup1" href="naturecorgis.html"><h2>Nature Corgis</h2><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="images/bone.png" alt="corgibone" width="75" height="75" />
                </div>
        </div>
```

or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xoLk5gjn/).

Comment: Boy do I feel like a complete idiot right now. Thank you so much haha